# extern keyword is different from c to c++?

Tags: c++, extern

I am a newbie of c++, and learning extern keyword now, I check some tutorial, it mentions extern "C", I am confused with it. what is the difference with extern?
and can anyone provide me some tutorial about how extern means in C++?

Comment: Which C++ book are you learning from that doesn't cover this, and the other things you have asked about here? This site is not intended to provide tutorials.

Comment: @unapersson if my post does brother you, you can skip it, and keep silence.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not going to do that.

Answer (score 2):

`extern "C"` is a C++ construct to allow you to link C and C++ code together.  For a "tutorial", see the FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html.

Answer (score 0):

`extern "C"` means that the compiler should generate C-style name mangling for the C++ function defined with it so that C code can call that C++ function.